# Async gevent Application server

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, wsgi, gevent, gunicorn

I am writing an application server where I want to have:
1) Async IO operation
2) Config based server management with options like reload, deamon mode, worker count, pid file, logging etc.

I found that gevent wsgi is a perfect match for my requirements, but the server management part is missing in it, for that I am thinking of using 
1) Guicorn, or
2) Nginx fastcgi

and for parsing http request I am using werkzeug.

Can anyone suggest which one to go ahead with or any other suggestion?

Thanks,
Anurag

Answer (score 0):

Look at [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/). It supports gevent async mode and has everything you are asking for and even more.